# Calling a function inside a function

Tags: python, function

this is a simple thing and I have no idea why this doesn't work as I've done this many times before in other languages, maybe I'm missing something. Anyway I have a function that does something and I try to call that function when I call a different function.

Context : puzzle is literally a puzzle made by rows and columns of strings and word is the word we're looking for in the puzzle

First function

```
def lr_occurrences(puzzle, word):    
    return puzzle.count(word)
```

Second function

```
def do_tasks(puzzle, name):    
    print('Number of times', name, 'occurs left-to-right: ', end='')       
    lr_occurrences(puzzle, name)
```

Yet when I call

```
do_tasks(PUZZLE1,'whatever')
```

in the shell, the only thing that pops up is the "Number of times..." thing, however if I call

```
lr_occurences(PUZZLE1,'whatever')
```

it works perfectly fine returning the value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `lr_occurrences(puzzle, name)` and then discarding the result. Either print it like you do earlier in that function, or return it.

```
def do_tasks(puzzle, name):    
    print('Number of times', name, 'occurs left-to-right: ', end='')       
    print(lr_occurrences(puzzle, name))
```

Or:

```
def do_tasks(puzzle, name):    
    print('Number of times', name, 'occurs left-to-right: ', end='')       
    return lr_occurrences(puzzle, name)
```

If you return it, you will have to print the call to `do_tasks`, e.g. `print(do_tasks(PUZZLE1,'whatever'))`, for it to show up.

Comment: Ahhhhh I tried printing it but it gave a syntax error so I thought i was wrong, turns out I forgot to put the brackets haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You never do anything with the return value. Either return it or print it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `do_tasks` function should look like this:

```
def do_tasks(puzzle, name):    
    print('Number of times', name, 'occurs left-to-right: ', end='')       
    return lr_occurrences(puzzle, name)
```

Note the added `return` so that the value returned by `lr_occurrences` to `do_tasks` is then returned by `do_tasks` to its caller.